# How to reuse Ui Component

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I have a working Ui Component:

`component1.js`:

```javascript
define(['UiComponent'], function(Component) {
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            'template': 'template1.html',
            'variable': 'component1'
        })
    }
)
```

`tempate1.html`:

```html
Hello <span data-bind="text: variable"></span>
```

`content.phtml`:

```html
<div id="component1" data-bind="scope: 'component1'">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#component1": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "component1": {
                        "component": "My_Module/js/view/component1"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I want to reuse this component in the same page with different template. E.g.

`template2.html`:

```html
Another hello <span data-bind="text: variable"></span>
```

I tried this:

```html
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#component1": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "component1": {
                        "component": "My_Module/js/view/component1"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "#component2": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "component2": {
                        "component": "My_Module/js/view/component1",
                        "defaults": {
                            "template": "template2.html"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

But it is not working. Is that possible? How can I do it? Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: On what conditions would you switch between both templates?

Comment: I want to display them both on a same page. One in header and one in sidebar for example.

Comment: Did you extend reference containers in `default.xml` file for header and sidebar?

Comment: Can you provide your PHTML where the #component1 element is please?

Comment: @Abdul I used initialization in a `phtml` file.

Comment: @Ben I updated the question, please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to override `defaults` properties using the component properties.

````
    {
        "#component1": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "component1": {
                        "component": "My_Module/js/view/component1"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "#component2": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "component2": {
                        "component": "My_Module/js/view/component1",
                        "template": "My_Module/template2.html"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>```
````

Comment: Wow it is really that simple. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have just missed it out from the question the problem is there is no element that matches the selector `#component2`.

```
    "#component2": {.   <--------------- This is a selector
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "component2": {
                    "component": "My_Module/js/view/component1",
                    "defaults": {
                        "template": "template2.html"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The line I have marked out is a selector, so the script will only initiliaze if an element exists with the ID of `component2` which it does not in your question. If you want the script to run ALWAYS regardless of selector then you can pass in the wildcard selector - `*` instead of a selector.